# Multiple users creating directory in server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm facing a issue where I don't even know what the right question to ask the Google gods.

I'm creating a PDF web application that will merge, split, and delete pages from a PDF document. I've already created all the methods to do the merge, split, and delete pages from a previous PDF project that was for a standalone windows machine, but working with web(C# and ASP.NET) with no prior experience has been very challenging(ZERO experience with C#, .NET, ASP.NET, and Web Dev).

Currently I have an issue of multiple users trying to use my PDF web applications at once. I just recently learned about Sessions and have used that and a directory structure that uses the computer Windows username as the directory name.

For example, if a user uses my web program, I wanted the code to create a directory for them base on their computer username and place all their uploaded PDF documents in it and also any edited PDF document they created.

The directory structure would be like

`.......(project path)......\Data\User1`

if there is a 2nd user then it would be

`.......(project path).......\Data\User2`

MY question: Is there other ways of handling this without having to create custom directory? The reason I ask is because giving users write access to create directory isn't something the senior dev's wants me to do for security reasons.

Are there ways for multiple users to upload to the same folder and distinguish each other apart(I have no idea)? 
what if multiple users uploaded a file with the same name but different content?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you can uniquely identify the user you could include that as part of the filenames.

Comment: A web application cannot modify the structure of the file system of the computer running the application through a web browser. They will have to manage the File system structure on their own and upload/download the PDFs in your application, or you will have to have storage available for them on your server.

Comment: @Zer0, OMG that's a great idea THANK YOU. Why couldn't I think of this. I will try this out right away.